# $(this).find is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show/hide some content when I click on a tr and it is somehow not working. This is the simplified code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="showDetails()">
        <td>Some text
            <br> <span class="hiddenContent">Some hidden content</span>

        </td>
        <td>Some More Text
            <br> <span class="hiddenContent">Some hidden content</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="showDetails()">
        <td>Some text
            <br> <span class="hiddenContent">Some hidden content</span>

        </td>
        <td>Some More Text
            <br> <span class="hiddenContent">Some hidden content</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showDetails() {
    $(".hiddenContent").hide();

    $(this).find(".hiddenContent").show();
}
```

Comment: By "somehow not working" do you mean that `. hiddenContent` is supposed to show but it isn't?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the clicked element.

Comment: Yes KJ Price, that's exactly what I mean. 
Vohuman, what does it refer to?

Comment: in your `onclick` event, pass `this` and access it in the showDetails( ) function

Comment: @Smiley The `window` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `this` refers to the `window` object.

If you want `this` to be bound to the clicked element, you could invoke the function with the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and pass `this`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/skg1sfvw/)

```
<tr onclick="showDetails.call(this)"></tr>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also just pass a reference to `this` as a parameter:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lefx9jz/)

```
<tr onclick="showDetails(this)"></tr>
```

```
function showDetails(el) {
    $(".hiddenContent").hide();

    $(el).find(".hiddenContent").show();
}
```

---

The better approach would be to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and attach an event listener to the `tr` elements instead:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mr6yv2o/)

```
$('tr').on('click', function () {
    $(".hiddenContent").hide();
    $(this).find(".hiddenContent").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much solved it. As soon as I am able to do so, I will accept it as an answer :)